# Дать каждому файлу рандомное имя

Tags: c#, коллекции, случайные-числа

Создал массив с путями до файлов и создал коллекцию в которую поместил массив.
Далее написал цикл, который копирует содержимое файлов и дает им рандомные имена, но цикл работает не правильно. Если нужно скопировать  3 файла и дать им рандомные имена, копируется каждый файл в один и тот же файл с одним рандомным именем. Как исправить цикл, чтобы при каждом копирование новому файлу давалось новое рандомное имя, пока цикл не закончится?
P.S. Для рандомным имен использую функцию `Path.GetRandomFileName();`
Создал пока массив с одним путем для нового файла, но в массиве нужно знать число элементов, в моем случае я не знаю за ранее сколько элементов будет, так как List обрабатываю в цикле и удаляю несуществующие пути. Если создать строку string  с                                                                    `"C:\\"+ Path.GetRandomFileName()+".txt"` , то эффект такой же, создается только один файл.

```
 string[] pathlog =
            {
                "\\folder\\folder\\tets1.txt",
                "\\folder\\folder\\tets2.txt",
                "\\folder\\folder\\tets3.txt"

            };

   string locc2 = "C:\\pass.txt"; //в этот файл все записывается
  string[] locc =
            {
                $"C:\\"+ Path.GetRandomFileName()
            };
 List<string> passion = new List<string>(pathlog);

for (int i = 0; i < passion.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int n = 0; n < locc.Length; n++)
                {
                    if (!File.Exists(locc[n]))

                        File.Copy(passion[i], locc[n], true);

                    using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(locc2))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine("This");
                        sw.WriteLine("is Extra");
                        sw.WriteLine("Text");

                    }
                }
            }
```

P.S. Представлен только основной код, он работает ровно так как описано в вопросе. Важно, разобраться только в функции копирования с рандомным именем, пока цикл не закончится

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените это

```
 File.Copy(passion[i], locc[n], true);
```

на это

```
 var randomFileName = $"C:\\"+ Path.GetRandomFileName();
 File.Copy(passion[i], randomFileName, true);
```

То есть создавайте путь к временному файлу внутри вашего цикла, а не 1 раз в начале программы.

Comment: добавил после `if (!File.Exists(locc[n]))
` VS стал ругаться, внедренный оператор не может являться объявлением, перенес var выше проверки существования файла, запустил программу, все равно создается одна копия файла

Comment: @Bortman если вы создаете путь ко временному файлу в цикле, то вам переменная locc вообще нигде больше не нужна, вам надо заменить все locc[n] на randomFileName

Comment: извиняюсь! VS заглючила, Ваш совет помог отлично! Теперь создается нужное количество копий файла. Теперь это запомню)Спасибо)

Comment: @Bortman пожалуйста. Если ответ действительно помог решить вашу проблему, отметье его галочкой.

Comment: проблема решена, галочку поставил)

Comment: @Bortman спасибо